# Don't understand the why configparser can't find the config file

Tags: python, jenkins, configparser

I'm using `cofigparser` in my python project. Directory structure is as following:

```
root/dir/data.py
root/dir/config.ini
```

`data.py` code:

```
config_parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config_file_path = "data/config.ini"
config_parser.read_file(open(config_file_path))
```

This works from local machine. But when Im trying to build it from Jenkins, output is:

```
> config_parser.read_file(open(config_file_path)) 19:09:04
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'data/config.ini'
```

After many attempts to resolve it I find out, that from Jenkins it works only if I include root to the path, so as I change it as following:

```
config_file_path = "root/data/config.ini"
```

It starts working on Jenkins. But - I have above error message on local machine now. So now Im in the situation, that if I can run my code from local machine, I have to change that path, and don`t forget to change it back, when Im commiting changes to git. Has anybody any idea, why is that? And how to write the path which will work on both?

Note1:

All the imports Im using in project are without root directory included, so for example:

```
from dir.dir2 import foo
```

If I include root dir, it never works from Jenkins.

Note2:

Both machines running Windows.

Comment: `config_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "data", "config.ini")`

Comment: @nosklo thanks a lot, it works perfectly! Anyway, still don`t understand the differences.

Comment: The "current directory" (as returned by `os.getcwd()`) is different on each of your methods of execution. The code I provided uses the path of the script as reference and not the current directory.